# My CSS animations don't work on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a CSS and JS. Its simply when I slide down to page my logo coming from left with opacity 0. Then when I came back to top again its going back and opacity being 0. Its working on computer and android phones. But on iOS devices its doesn't work. What is wrong with on my code?

Logo is coming after I slide to top it moves to the left but does not disappear. Thank you for responses .

JS:

```
const handleToggle = (e) => {
    let brands = document.getElementsByClassName("stickyBrand"); //Its my logo.
    if (e) {
      Array.from(brands).forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.add("fadeInLeft");
        el.classList.remove("fadeOutLeft");
      });
    } else {
      Array.from(brands).forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.add("fadeOutLeft");
        el.classList.remove("fadeInLeft");
      });
    }
  };
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutAnimationOperaSafari {
  0% {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50px);
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need prefixes for CSS transforms anymore. Unless you want to support 10 year old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -webkit- prefixes to your transforms. On iOS, all browsers use safari webkit (because they are based on uiwebview), and currently iOS webkit only supports transforms with a prefix. 
What you are seeing is that the transform is always 0 throughout the animation because the non-prefixed selector is not used.

Comment: `-webkit-` hasn't been needed transform for Safari on iOS since iOS 9 which was released in 2015. https://caniuse.com/?search=transform

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).